# windows 10 calendar and google calendar

Tags: windows-10, sync, calendar, google-calendar

I have the new W10 calendar app set to sync with my google calendar. New events entered into google cal appear in the W10 calendar, but new ones entered into W10 do not appear in google. Is this correct? Is "sync" only a one way process in which one calendar has to be used as the "master"?

Answer (score 0):

No, from my personal private POV (and my Win10 Pro 1703) I can't confirm this behavior:

1. You can't create **pure local** event in Calendar App (if you have linked some external calendars): you must to select (one) linked calendar from list
2. Created event will appear in this remote calendar (maybe not immediately, but after scheduled sync - I didn't test it yet) and in local calendar (in app)

And yes, you *will have troubles* with syncing of calendars, but in slightly different style, if you have more than 1 external calendar and these calendars can't synchronize data among themselves... but this is an another story about sitting on a set of chairs and incompatible tools

Do you want to see screenshots from my side and|or some shared tests is RW-shared Google Calendar?